# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' (VS Code with Anaconda interpreter)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

Hi I'm really new on the programming. I am using VS Code with Anaconda interpreter:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1nDb.jpg)

I am using Windows 10

I want to import "requests" module on my VS Code. I opened cmd and wrote "pip3 install requests" but it told me "Requirment already satisfied:" etc... Then I tried to download with Anaconda. I opened my cmd and wrote "conda install requests" and I downloaded.

Then I wrote this code to try module: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3FfS.jpg)

But I received an error in VS Code like that: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dW0z.jpg)

What can I do to solve this problem? Thank you so much for your answers. (By the way, sorry for my bad English :D I hope I explained my problem.)

Comment: you probably got something wrong with paths, you didn't say what operating system ure on, probably Windows if VC

Comment: Yes I'm using win10

Comment: @quinn Always try writing the code segment & the error in the question itself, instead of attaching it as pictures.

Comment: why dont u try changing the interpretter? to something like the official python interpretter, installed ? the error is because u dont have `request` installed on the `base` virtualenv

Comment: Why use pip to install requests? You should use a new/separate Conda environment, by the way, don't use base for development. Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 1):

[image: pic]

Click in bottom left cornet in VS code on (Python <Version>) and then choose the python version that in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the answer. In VS Code, I open powershell and write "py (filename).py". But just now, I tried to click top-right button which name is "Run Python File in Terminal" (green button). Then code executed successfully. I didn't take an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following prospects in vscode with python extension:

1. When selecting interpreter, press **ctrl+shift+'** to open a new integrated terminal. If you selected base:conda environment, the terminal should be like this:
   [image]
2. Then use `pip list` to show modules you've installed, if module `requests` not there, type commands `pip install requests`in the terminal;
3. click [image] then `create a launch.json file`, select `Python File`. This creates and opens a launch.json. You can close it or add configurations you want. More guidance about debug configurations you can reference: [Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging). Press F5 to run your code.

Just make sure the module installation is in the same environment as interpreter you've selected.